# [ERROR]: Incorrect value: Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Shipment\Type in: eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_code=shipment_type

Tags: magento2

I'm migrating data from **magento 1.9.2.1** to **magento 2.0.2**, when it gets to step EAV.I 'm getting the following error:

> [ERROR]: Incorrect value:
>   Magento\Bundle\Model\Product\Attribute\Source\Shipment\Type in:
>   eav_attribute.source_model for attribute_code=shipment_type

I double checked the values in the old and new. they match exactly.I tried to ignore and didn't work for this in the **class-map.xml**.

Any Ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all please check if app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Model/Product/Type.php file exist in your system or not.

If not then you can find the file at the following link -

http://freegento.com/doc/d7/d42/_bundle_2_model_2_product_2_type_8php-source.html

Copy the file and paste it at app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Model/Product

location by name Type.php and then perform the migration.

It would be better if you could share the data of your class-map.xml file here?

If that does not work then try to edit the node and replace Magento (if exist) with Mage and then try again.

Also, you can try removing that node from the class-map.xml file and run migration. If successful then you will have to convert the app/code/core/Mage/Bundle/Model/Product/Type.php file manually.